# New-SCWebDeployPackage is not recognized

Tags: azure, sitecore

I'm trying to package a Sitecore solution and followed the instructions mentioned in the following URLs.
https://doc.sitecore.net/cloud/working_with_sitecore_azure/configuring_sitecore_azure/getting_started_with_sitecore_azure_toolkit?roles=developer

https://doc.sitecore.net/cloud/working_with_sitecore_azure/configuring_sitecore_azure/package_a_sitecore_solution_for_the_azure_app_service?roles=developer

I have PowerShell (5.0). I have also updated Azure PowerShell Module 3.1.0

When I run the command Start-SitecoreAzurePackaging with all the options specified in the Sitecore documentation, I get the following error.

The term 'New-SCWebDeployPackage' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Am I missing something?

Thanks,
Prawin

Answer (score 1):

run the below line before you run the command.

Import-Module [your path]\Cloud.Services.Provisioning.SDK\tools\Sitecore.Cloud.CmdLets.dll

Comment: I followed the same, but i'm getting 

"New-SCWebDeployPackage : System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\App_Data'."